# Erro na função jason_decode()

Tags: php, api

Bem, estou fazendo uma página simples para consumir dados de uma api do wikipedia através de um pequeno formulário:

```
    <form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="busca">
    <input type="submit" value="Busca">
</form>

<?php

    if($_GET['busca']){
        $api_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=".ucwords($_GET['busca']).".redirects=true";
        $api_url = str_replace(' ', '%20', $api_url);

        if($data = jason_decode(file_get_contents($api_url))){
            foreach($data->query->pages as $key=>$val){
                $pageId =$key;
                break;
            }
            $conteudo = $data->query->pages->$pageId->extract;

            header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
            echo $content;
        }
        else{
            echo 'Nenhum resultado encontrado.';
        }
    }
?>
```

O php informa

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function jason_decode()

Como podemos ver abaixo, a extensão json está funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cheguei a achar que era por causa da verificação com IF, mas o erro persiste.

Comment: O correto é `json_decode`

Comment: sugiro prestar mais atenção nos detalhes, no erro está claramente **jason** e o correto é **json**

Comment: Nossa... "Jason"... Obg Pessoal

Comment: agora recebo a seguinte msg: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$extract in C:\xampp\htdocs\wiki\index.php on line 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto é json_decode() e não jason_decode()

Comment: Nossa... "Jason" foi f...   Vlw cara.